# Basic randomized algorithm recurrence

Tags: algorithm, random, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I'm having trouble fully understanding how to write the recurrence for the expected running time of a randomized algorithm.

I believe I'm doing it correctly, but if someone could look over it, that'd be a huge help.

Here's the pseudocode for the algorithm:

```
printIntegers(A, n)   // an array A of integers is the input, with n integers
    if A.length > 0
        for i = 1 to n
            print A[i]
        randInt = rand(1, 10)
        if randInt != 10
            return
        else 
            printIntegers(A, n-1)
```

The only random part is the random generator between 1 and 10. I'm trying to understand how that would translate in the recurrence.

I'm thinking:

```
T(n) = O(n)               if a != 10     probability = 9/10
       T(n-1) + O(n)         a = 10                  = 1/10 
       T(n-2) + O(n)
       ....
       T(0) + O(n)
```

This makes sense in my head, and then the expected running time would be O(n).  Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the initial condition should use `n` in the check, not `A.length` since the latter is not changing in the recursion.

The `expected` number of times the recursion will be called is `0.1`. The expectation is the same as the probability the recursion will be called. In the current case, if the random number generator is truly random, the number `10` will appear `1/10` of the times. Likewise, the expected number of times there will be no recursion is `0.9`. But the `O(n)` appears in both the cases, so the equation will be, when considering *expected values*:

```
T(n) = (0.9 + 0.1) * O(n) + 0.1 * T(n-1)
     = O(n) + 0.1 * T(n-1)
     = O(n) + 0.1 * (O(n-1) + 0.1 * T(n-2))
     = O(n) + 0.1 * O(n-1) + 0.1^2 * O(n-2) +...
     = O(n) * (0.1 + 0.1^2 +...+0.1^(n-1)) + 0.1^(n-1) * T(1)
     = O(n) * (1 - 0.1^n)/0.9 + K
```

The above is `O(n * (1 - 0.9^n)/0.9)` which is essentially the same as `O(n)` depending upon your accuracy needs.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind detailing the equation without considering expected values? It's throwing me off a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First note that:

```
T(n) = n + (n-1)/10 + (n-2)/10^2 + ... + 1/10^{n-1}
```

Then, bounding T(n) above:

```
T(n) = n + (n-1)/10 + (n-2)/10^2 + ... + 1/10^{n-1}
     < n + n/10 + n/10^2 + ... + n/10^{n-1}
     = n(1 + 1/10 + ... + 1/10^{n-1})
     < n(1 + 1/10 + 1/10^2 + ...)
     = n/(1 - 1/10) = 10n/9
```

and bounding it below:

```
T(n) = n + (n-1)/10 + (n-2)/10^2 + ... + 1/10^{n-1}
     > n
```

So `n < T(n) < 10n/9` and `T(n)` is `Theta(n)`.